# NOT NULL constraint failed: store_customer.first_name

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

NOT NULL constraint failed: store_customer.first_name
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/
Django Version: 4.1.4
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:
NOT NULL constraint failed: store_customer.first_name

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):

   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
   password = models.CharField(max_length=500)


   def register(self):
       self.save()

  def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

views.py

```
def signup(request):

  if request == 'GET':
      return render(request, 'signup.html')

  else:
    first_name = request.POST.get('firstname')
    last_name = request.POST.get('lastname')
    phone = request.POST.get('phone')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    customer = Customer(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name,phone=phone,email=email,password=password)
    customer.register()

   

    # return HttpResponse( 'signup successful' )
    return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

Comment: request.POST.get('firstname') must be empty, that's why it is giving the null error for first_name

Comment: try to use django forms for the validations part https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to handle `GET` requests it's automatically handled by Django Just handle `POST` requests like this...

#### models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

#### views.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request == 'POST': #<------- handled POST request
        first_name = request.POST.get('firstname')
        last_name = request.POST.get('lastname')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        customer = Customer(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name,phone=phone,email=email,password=password)
        customer.save()
        return redirect('/signup/')
    return render(request, 'signup.html') #<------- handled GET request
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending first name in the form? By default 'models.CharField' has a null and 'blank' option set to false [Django ref.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/) - this means that the it need to be set to something different that null when saving.

Your error suggests that the first_name was not sent in POST request (from form).